# finding the dimension of a matrix, the sum of whose rows is zero

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space of $n\times n$ matrices over $R$ and Let $W$ be subspaceof matrices with entries in each row adding upto zero.then the dimension is?

1. n
2. $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$
3. $n(n-1)$
4. $n-1$

can someone please explain me this?

Comment: Suppose you know that a matrix is in $W$. If you know the first $n - 1$ entries of a row, what can you say about the last entry? What does this say about the dimension of $W$?

Comment: if first n-1 entries add upto zero..then last one will be zero????

Comment: That's true, and what if the first $n - 1$ entries add up to something other than zero?

Comment: yeah...then last entry will have n elements..if so..how can we say all row elements add upto zero?

Answer (score 1):

In each row $i$, you can arbitrarily select $n-1$ values $\{ a_{ij} \}_{j=1}^{n-1}$ to be the values in the first $n-1$ entries. On the other hand, given these entries, $a_{in}$ is determined: we must have $a_{in} = -\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} a_{ij}$. So, by repeating this argument in each row, we get that a matrix in this set is specified by a choice of $n(n-1)$ parameters, so the dimension of the set is $n(n-1)$.

One would formalize this argument by presenting a basis. This is not so hard to do, and the idea is very similar to what I wrote above. Hint: try matrices which have exactly two nonzero entries.

Answer (score 0):

By saying that the sum of the elements of each row is zero, you have $n$ independant linear relations between elements ($\sum{\text{values of one row}} = 0$ for each row), and that the only ones (besides the same multiplied by a non-zero number). So your "dimension" for the space of a row is $n^2 - n = n(n-1)$

More illustrated :
Each row is independant so let's focus first on one row
You can choose $n-1$ values and the last one is fixed to $-\sum{other values}$ to verify that the sum of the elements of the row is $0$.
Thus you have $n-1$ independant elements (so $dim \ge n-1$) and one element determinated by the others (so $dim \le n-1$)
Moreover each row is independant from the other so the total dimension is numberOfRow * "dimensionOfOneRow"
So it would be reponse 3. $n(n-1)$